# Trouble GETing over HTTPS on the ESP32

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I am having some trouble doing a GET request over HTTPS on the ESP32. I am using the `BasicHttpsClinet` example from the ArduenoIDE. Here is the code.

```
/**
   BasicHTTPSClient.ino

Created on: 14.10.2018

*/

#include <Arduino.h>

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>

#include <HTTPClient.h>

#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

const char* rootCACertificate = \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"\
"super_secret certificate"\
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

// Not sure if WiFiClientSecure checks the validity date of the certificate. 
// Setting clock just to be sure...
void setClock() {
  configTime(0, 0,"cn.pool.ntp.org", "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");

  Serial.print(F("Waiting for NTP time sync: "));
  time_t nowSecs = time(nullptr);
  while (nowSecs < 8 * 3600 * 2) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(F("."));
    yield();
    nowSecs = time(nullptr);
  }

  Serial.println();
  struct tm timeinfo;
  gmtime_r(&nowSecs, &timeinfo);
  Serial.print(F("Current time: "));
  Serial.print(asctime(&timeinfo));
}


WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Serial.setDebugOutput(true);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFiMulti.addAP("Master_2.4G", "wittyercheese551");

  // wait for WiFi connection
  Serial.print("Waiting for WiFi to connect...");
  while ((WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED)) {
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println(" connected");

  setClock();  
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClientSecure *client = new WiFiClientSecure;
  if(client) {
    client -> setCACert(rootCACertificate);

    {
      // Add a scoping block for HTTPClient https to make sure it is destroyed before WiFiClientSecure *client is 
  HTTPClient https;

  Serial.print("[HTTPS] begin...\n");
  if (https.begin(*client, "https://my_end_point.com/something_or_other")) {  // HTTPS
    Serial.print("[HTTPS] GET...\n");
    // start connection and send HTTP header
    int httpCode = https.GET();

    // httpCode will be negative on error
    if (httpCode > 0) {
      // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
      Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);

      // file found at server
      if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
        String payload = https.getString();
        Serial.println(payload);
      }
    } else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... failed, error: %s\n", https.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
    }

    https.end();
  } else {
    Serial.printf("[HTTPS] Unable to connect\n");
  }

  // End extra scoping block
}

delete client;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unable to create client");
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Waiting 10s before the next round...");
  delay(10000);
}
```

I am getting the following when I run the sketch

```
[HTTPS] GET... failed, error: send header failed
```

Guessing this is related to the issue reported here: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/2670

I tried updating my esp-arduino libraries( to get the latest code with the fix mentioned in the Github issue) by redoing the steps from here: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/docs/arduino-ide/mac.md#installation-instructions-for-mac-os

But I still get the same issue error.

I have double-checked my server, I know that the esp32 has not managed to make it to the endpoint yet.

I have tested the GET endpoint in my browser and it works fine. I have compared the certificate to the one hardcoded in the sketch file. They match.

How do I update my arduino-esp32 libraries to get the fix mentioned in the GitHub issue?